# How to use openmodelica compiler in CLI?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to use OpenModelica compiler(omc) in the [CLI](https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/omchelptext.html#omcflag-debug-section), so I use the `Terminal`provided in OMEdit.
I tried to debug `Modelica.Blocks.Examples.PID_Controller`, but it seems omc couldn't find this model.

[image: en]

So I duplicated the `PID_Controller` model and put into a folder, then switched working directory in the CLI. At this time, omc could access the model, but it couldn't find the base model of `Modelica.Icon.Example`, I am guessing that omc doesn't have access to the `Modelica Standard Library(MSL)` loaded in the OMEdit.

My question is how to let omc load the `MSL` correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-d` are debug flags used in general by the developers

If you want to use omc from command line the easiest is to use .mos scripts:

The script: c:\writable\directory\script.mos

```
loadModel(Modelica); getErrorString(); // load the Modelica Standard Library (MSL)
simulate(Modelica.Blocks.Examples.PID_Controller); getErrorString(); // simulate a model
plotAll(); getErroString(); // plot all variables
```

Then from the command line, go to a directory where you can generate some output:

```
cd c:\writable\directory\
omc script.mos
```

See all the available API (the commands you can put in a mos script) here:
  https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/OpenModelica.Scripting.html